# A VBA vlookup function

Tags: vba, excel

If I had columns like:

```
ColA     ColB
----     ----
emp      NUMBER
dept     DATE
name     VARCHAR
```

I need a vba function that I could use as follows:

```
If IS_NUMBER(A1) = "T" Then
  //stuff
End If
```

and could be simply modified for:

```
If IS_VARCHAR(A3) = "T" Then
  //stuff
End If
```

Actually it might be better if it worked like (basically the 2nd parameter is doing a lookup on the cell to the right):

```
If DataType(A3, "VARCHAR") = "T" Then
  //stuff
End If
```

Comment: In column B, do you have actual words 'NUMBER', 'DATE', 'VARCHAR' or some values of these types?

Comment: actual words 'NUMBER', 'DATE', 'VARCHAR' in column B

Comment: -1 Not clear what you're trying to accomplish. Looks like you just need a `VLOOKUP` worksheet function, but that's just a guess. Clarify and I'll un-downvote.

Comment: yes, it is just a vlookup function for the cell to the right. so i can check does the cell on the left have the string "xyz" on the right.

Comment: Please post your own answer as an answer, not an edit to your question. Then accept your own answer to mark the question as solved.

Comment: @Jean, he did it. (but it takes a while before you can accept your own answer).

Comment: He did it after I encouraged him to do so.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's how I ended up coding it:

```
Public Function get_data_type(Cell As Range, Text As String) As String 

  Dim dtype As String  
  dtype = Cell.Offset(0, 1).Value  
  If dtype = Text Then     
    get_data_type = "T" 
  Else     
    get_data_type = "F" 
  End If  

End Function  

Sub test() 

  If get_data_type(Range("F5187"), "VARCHAR") = "T" Then  
    '// do stuff 
  End If 

End Sub
```

Another method:

```
Public Function get_data_type(Cell As Range) As String 

  Dim dtype As String  
  dtype = Cell.Offset(0, 1).Value 
  get_data_type = dtype  

End Function  

Sub test() 

  If get_data_type(Range("F5187")) = "VARCHAR" Then  
    '//stuff
  End If 

End Sub
```

Comment: Side note: if by "T" you mean True and by "F" you mean False,you may want to consider using a Boolean. Your second method is much more clear as `get_data_type`does get the data type instead of checking it.

Answer (score 1):

If you named your lookup table as a named range, say to `map`, you could use the following code:

```
Option Explicit

Function get_type(field As Variant)

  Dim map As Range
  Set map = Range("map")

  On Error Resume Next
    get_type = WorksheetFunction.vlookup(field, map, 2, 0)
  On Error GoTo 0

End Function

Sub test_get_type()

  Debug.Print get_type("emp")
  Debug.Print get_type("dept")
  Debug.Print get_type("name")

End Sub
```

The function `get_type()` simply acts as a passthrough to the `vlookup()` function.